# Does precision influence performance with MongoDB GeoSpatial Queries?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial, mongodb-geospatial

Consider a query of:

```
db.stuff.find({ Location:
   { $geoWithin:
      { $centerSphere: [ [ -73.93414657, 40.82302903 ], 5 / 3963.2 ] } } })
```

Would it be reasonable to expect a performance boost if the coordinates were less precise? If so, by how much?

```
db.stuff.find({ Location:
   { $geoWithin:
      { $centerSphere: [ [ -73.93414, 40.82302 ], 5 / 3963.2 ] } } })
```

Bonus points if you have links to documentation on performance tuning mongo geospatial queries.

Comment: Why would it? Isn't -73.93414 equally precise to -73.93414657 float?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no.

And you can test this yourself by looking at `$executionStats`.
Be aware that you should change the coordinated on every call to avoid metric distortion due to caching.

More info about mongodb's spatial B-tree indexing [here](https://www.slideshare.net/nknize/rtree-spatial-indexing-with-mongodb-mongodc).